# I want to add new data from second table to main table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add new data to the main table using the checkbox option, but the data added is not the same as the selected data. this is my code ...

```
<table border="1" id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>Raka</td>
                <input type="hidden" id="fname" value="Raka">
                <td>Gilbert</td>
                <input type="hidden" id="lname" value="Gilbert">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Achyar</td>
                <input type="hidden" id="fname" value="Achyar">
                <td>Lucas</td>
                <input type="hidden" id="lname" value="Lucas">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '#Add', function() {
            $("table").find('input[name="chk"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    var fname = $('#fname').val();
                    var lname = $('#lname').val();

                    var newData = '<tr>'+
                                  '<td>'+fname+'</td>'+
                                  '<td>'+lname+'</td>'+
                                  '<tr>';
                    $('table').append(newData);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: you have multiple elements with the same id attribute, thats why it wont work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `id="fname"` to `class="fname"` and get the input value closest to checkbox. Currently you are getting data from the first inputs as they have the same id's.

```js
function valueExists(value) {

if (!value) {
  return true;
}

let exists = false;

$("#main-table").find('tr').each(function() {
  let fname = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text(),
  lname = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
  
  const fullName = `${fname}${lname}`;

  
  if (value.toLowerCase() === fullName.toLowerCase()) {
    exists = true;
  }
});

return exists;

}

$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
      $("table").find('input[name="chk"]').each(function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          
          var fname = $(this).parents('tr').find('.fname').val();
          var lname = $(this).parents('tr').find('.lname').val();
          
          if (valueExists(`${fname}${lname}`)) return;
          

          var newData = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + fname + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + lname + '</td>' +
            '<tr>';
          $('#main-table').append(newData);
        }
      });
    })
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Main Table</h1>
<table class="table table-dark" border="1" id="main-table">
</table>

<hr>

<h1>Second table</h1>

<table border="1" id="table2">
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Raka</td>
      <input type="hidden" class="fname" value="Raka">
      <td class="last">Gilbert</td>
      <input type="hidden" class="lname" value="Gilbert">
      <td><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Achyar</td>
      <input type="hidden" class="fname" value="Achyar">
      <td class="last">Lucas</td>
      <input type="hidden" class="lname" value="Lucas">
      <td><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button" id="add" name="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: if the data to be added already exists, then the checkbox must be disabled. what should i change?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used plain javascript

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("input[name='chk']")].forEach(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.checked) {
      const fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      const lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

      const newData = `<tr><td>${ fname }</td><td>${ lname }</td</tr>`;
        // "<tr>" + "<td>" + fname + "</td>" + "<td>" + lname + "</td>" + "<tr>";
      document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML += newData;
    }
  });
});
```

Hope was useful. If any flaws please update

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that is not work for me. when I click the second data, the data appears to the first

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neater solution, using 2 tables as requested, without hidden inputs and a better use of 'tables' and 'trs' in jquery

```js
$(function(){

        $("#btnAdd").click(function(){
            let table1 = $("#table1");
                table2 = $("#table2");

            $.each(table2.find('tr'), function(i, tr){
                tr = $(tr);
                let new_tr = $('<tr>');
                if (tr.find("td input").is(":checked")) {
                    let fname = tr.find("td:nth-child(1)").html(),
                        lname = tr.find("td:nth-child(2)").html();

                    new_tr.append(
                        '<td>' + fname + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + lname + '</td>' +
                        '<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>'
                    );

                    table1.append(new_tr)
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TABLE 1
<table border="1" id="table1">

</table>

<hr/>

TABLE 2
<table border="1" id="table2">
    <tr>
        <td>Raka</td>
        <td>Gilbert</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Achyar</td>
        <td>Lucas</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add</button>
```